# What do Islam say about watching football?

Tags: sharia

What do Islam say about watching or/and playing football?

Comment: Questions of the form "What does Islam say about [topic]" are generally considered too vague to be readily answerable according to the Stack Exchange model.  See also relevant meta discussion here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1518/22

Answer (score 3):

Good question, I have never came across this. I don't think Islam has anything against watching/playing football, unless someone is forgetting the fundamentals of Islam (Prayer, fasting, modesty, respect for others etc.) because of playing/watching football.

This makes me think that what kind of games kids/adults might have played during the period of Prophet Muhammad (S.A.W).

Answer (score 3):

Playing football is allowed by Islam.

According to Wikipedia:

> The Islamic law, or Sharia, sets several bounds that indirectly impact Muslim athletes. This includes rules regarding the awrah, those parts of the body not to be exposed in public. The hijab or Burqas required by strict divisions of Islam can make it difficult for women to engage in many sports. Also, men are not allowed to have clothing that shows the area between the knees and navel, prohibiting them from engaging in, for example, Sumo wrestling. For some time, Iranian women at the Olympics only competed in shooting because it was the one area unaffected by their dress codes. To solve this, many sports companies have begun creating Muslim-friendly sportswear, particularly for Muslims, especially women, who practice martial arts such as kickboxing and taekwondo and can be worn in conjunction with the traditional keikogi or other associated uniform whilst still maintaining their modesty.

for more information you can take a look at this question on onislam.com
[How Does Islam View Sports and Exercise?](http://www.onislam.net/english/ask-about-islam/islam-and-the-world/worldview/166082-how-does-islam-view-sports-and-exercise.html)

Watching footbal is haraam most of the time, according to islamqa

> Football games that are shown on television include a number of things that are contrary to sharee‘ah: 
>   ·        In most cases -- if not all -- it may come under the category of gambling and betting which are haraam.
>   ·        They involve uncovering of ‘awrahs, mixing of men and women and listening to musical instruments. 
>   In addition to that, they are a waste of time, which is spent on something that is not beneficial and distracts one from that which is more beneficial to him in religious and worldly terms.

For more information check the source. 
[is it permissible to watch football (soccer) games on television?](http://islamqa.com/en/ref/146844)

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE, good answer but answers a part. What about watching the football? :)

Answer (score 0):

Football matches typically exhibit a lot of haram things like Awrah of the players , women who are not covered much and many more. Moreover the funding of these events come from riba based sources and banks which stand to make a huge profit from these matches. These matches also advertise Alcoholic drinks which again gain profits due to the marketing by the footbal matches.

According to [Fataawa al-Lajnah al-Daa’imah](http://islamqa.info/en/146844) (Permanent Committee to Issue Fatwas) watching  the current  FIFA world cup  is haram as it involves many of the harams mentioned in the fatawa.

[Source : IslamQA](http://islamqa.info/en/146844)